# Handling Nulls in a model passed over into a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

I am trying to fix these linq statements so that they wont error if the model is null.

For example:
`model.FilterSet.Dispositions` may be null. While `model.FilterSet.GenderFilters` may not.

My current linq statement gives error if there is a null so I tried to add `.Where(item => item != null)` in the DispositionFilters linq, but it gives me an error saying that this will always be true.

Here is my code:

```
var filters = new RespondentCSVFilters
            {
                CSVFilters = new CSVFilters 
                { 
                    DispositionFilters = model.FilterSet.Dispositions.Where(item=>item != null).ToList().ConvertAll(item => (int)((RespondentStatus)Enum.Parse(typeof(RespondentStatus), item.ToString()))),
                    EthnicitiesFilters = model.FilterSet.Ethnicities.ConvertAll(item => (int)((Ethnicity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Ethnicity), item.ToString()))),
                    GenderFilters = model.FilterSet.Genders.ConvertAll(item => (int)((Gender)Enum.Parse(typeof(Gender), item.ToString()))),
                    SourcesFilters = model.FilterSet.Sources.ConvertAll(item => (int)((RespondentSource)Enum.Parse(typeof(RespondentSource), item.ToString()))),
                }
            };
```

I am not sure how to make the changes in order to handle nulls.

Comment: Do you mean that `model.FilterSet.Dispositions` field of the model could be `null`, or that one of the items inside `model.FilterSet.Dispositions` could be `null`?

Comment: the field of the model could be null for instance model.FilterSet.Dispositions could be completely empty.

Comment: I would have broke up the lines to make that more readable

Comment: Define different lists for DispositionFilters, GenderFilters,... and then create your CSVFilters later on. You don't have to do everything in one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried to add .Where(item => item != null)

But this will only check each item for null, not the source ("Dispositions").  To check for null fluently (without adding a bunch of "if" statements), an `EmptyIfNull` extension can be helpful:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> EmptyIfNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> self)
    {
        return self == null ? Enumerable.Empty<T>() : self;
    }
}
```

Now you can write ...

```
model.FilterSet.Dispositions.EmptyIfNull().Where( ... )
```

and if `model.FilterSet.Dispositions` is null, you won't get an exception, but the statement will evaluate to an empty set.